# General solution of differential equation $y'-3y=e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'-3y=e^x$

I have no idea how to do it, I've seen some solutions but I don't understand them
[image]

Comment: You should post your attempt otherwise the post will be closed Franco.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a first order linear differential equation , so first you solve the homogeneous part $\dot y=3y$ with solution $Ke^{3x}$ and using the variation of constants method let be $$y(x)=K(x)e^{3x}\Longrightarrow 3K(x)e^{3x}+e^x=\dot y(x)=\dot k(x)e^{3x}+3e^{3x}K(x)$$
we take left and right side and we have $\dot K(x)=e^{-2x}$ and integrating both sides $K(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}$ and we replace $K(x)e^{3x}=y(x)$ as our particular solution and since the solution is the general solution of the homogeneous plus one particular our solution is $$Ke^{3x}-\frac{e^x}{2}$$

Comment: Please correct your English. What is "lineal EDO" ?

Comment: Thank you, I just uploaded an image of my attempt, now I realize what it was that I needed to complete the exercise

Comment: He wanted to say linear EDO (ordinary differential equation)

Answer (score 0):

Using an integrating factor, let let $I := e^{\int -3 dx}$, so $I := e^{-3x}$. Multiplying the entire equation by $I$,

$e^{-3x}y'-3e^{-3x}y=e^{-2x}$. Integrating both sides, we obtain $y(x)=C_1e^{3x}+\frac{e^x}{2}$